# Resultado en Rshiny

Tags: r, rstudio

buen día

Quisiera saber si es posible generar una lista de resultados en Rshiny, me explico: Cada que presiono un botón aparece un resultado en la pantalla, pero cuando vuelvo a presionar se cambia por el nuevo resultado, lo que quiero hacer es que se muestre el resultado en la pantalla y cada vez que se ejecute otro cálculo desplace el antiguo por el nuevo sin eliminarlo

Ejemplo:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Calculo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         numericInput("num", "Numero:", 1, min = 1, max = 100),
         actionButton('btnCalculo', 'Calcular',
                      btn_type = "button", type = "primary"),
    ),
      mainPanel(
         valueBoxOutput("valuebox2") 
      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output) {
   numero_input <- input$num
   result <- numero_input + 1000
   ### Outs
   output$valuebox2<-renderInfoBox({valueBox(format(round(result,0), big.mark = ","),"Suma")})
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola Adrián, seguramente es posible. Ahora, imagino que no es la respuesta que esperas, el problema es que tu consulta es bastante imprecisa y amplia (al menos para mí), sería bueno que muestres algún ejemplo de código de lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora, que nos describas en detalle cual es el comportamiento actual y que es lo que en realidad estarías queriendo hacer.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Añadí un pequeño ejemplo de lo que actualmente hace

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código realiza algo como  lo que necesitas

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Calculo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         numericInput("num", "Numero:", 1, min = 1, max = 100),
         actionButton('btnCalculo', 'Calcular',
                      btn_type = "button", type = "primary"),
    ),
      mainPanel(
         uiOutput("valuebox2")#valueBoxOutput("valuebox2") 
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

    rv<-reactiveValues(result=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$btnCalculo,{
        rv$result[input$btnCalculo] <- input$num + 1000
    })

    output$valuebox2<-renderUI({#renderInfoBox({
        if(is.null(rv$result)){
            div()
        }else(
            #valueBox(format(round(rv$result,0), big.mark = ","),"Suma")
            lapply(rev(rv$result), function(i) { 
                valueBox(format(round(i,0), big.mark = ","),"Suma")
            } )
        )
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```